# Lexar Professional 3600X SD Card Isn't Visible

Tags: memory, sd-card, camera

I have Lexar Professional Workflow CR2 card reader and a 256 GB Lexar Professional 3600x, but it seems like my card has an issue, when I insert the memory card inside card reader and plug the card reader's usb to computer, nothing happens except the blue light from card reader. I can see the card reader as a device in my computer but I can't see or explore my files as a drive. But, interestingly when I list the drives on my windows PC on command prompt; I can see an extra drive. But when I try to enter it via command prompt (by writing it's letter only like E:) I get "Device is not ready" as an answer.

I don't need the files inside the memory card, I just need to be able to use it again.

Edit: After list disk i see an additional Disk besides my HDDs with

```
No Media           0 B      0 B
```

and its' number is 2, after writing sel disk 2;

```
Disk 2 is now the selected disk.
```

list part;

```
There are no partitions on this disk to show.
```

list vol

```
 Volume 4     E                       Removable       0 B  No Media
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any idea? @K7AAY

Answer (score 0):

Now that it appears, here's a step-by-step suggestion for [DISKPART](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) thanks to [Helpdeskgeek.com](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/diskpart-windows-how-to-use/):

```
list disk  
select disk n  
clean  
list disk
```

(You'll see an asterisk next to the disk name)

```
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
format FS=NTFS label=Data quick
```

(You can change **Data** above to whatever you want, & use any unused drive letter below)

```
assign letter = x
exit
```

Comment: When I try to clean the disk, I get the following error;
`Virtual Disk Service error:
There is no media in the device.`